# Find similar numbers in a sequence and record the max consecutive streak

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have a long sequence of numbers and i want to record the longest consecutive streak of numbers in the list.

I want to increment a counter each time a number has a difference of 10 or less than the previous number. Example:

```
1
53
32
74
74
75
75
74
98
2
2
4
3
2
3
1
3
2
```

74,74,75,75,74 would be counted because they are less than 10 off from each other. So that would be a streak of 5. After that there's a 98 and an even longer streak. So since there's a longer streak the counter needs to discard the previous streak since it's not the biggest one. It basically resets.

```
list of numbers i'm working with: https://pastebin.com/aga6kkq2
```

Here is my current code:

```
vector<int> numbers;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size() - 1; i += 2)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << " first set \n" << numbers[i + 1] << " second set " << endl;
        int b = numbers[i];
        int a = numbers[i + 1];
        int difference = b - a;
        if (difference <= 10)
        {
            count++;
            if (difference > 10) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This gets the 1st pair of numbers and subtracts them for the difference to see if it's less than 10. I'm sure there's a way better approach. It isn't accurate and is off by 4. The longest consecutive streak in this list should be 140. What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your specific question? "Please write a better version of my code, for me" is not a question.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik How to find similar numbers in a sequence and record the max consecutive streak? It's in the title. The way i tried it obviously isn't working and that's why i'm here!

Comment: Well, the way to do it is to open a text editor, and write some C++ code that does this. That's the precise answer to your question.

Comment: That's cool. Anyways, my code isn't working and my question still remains unanswered. I didn't come here to be trolled by someone with 50k+ rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector<int> numbers;

// some code here to add values to the numbers array

int maxStreak = 0;
int counter = 0;
int previousNumber;
int currentNumber;
for (int i= 1; i < numbers.size(); i++)
{
    previousNumber = numbers[i - 1];
    currentNumber = numbers[i];

    if (abs(currentNumber - previousNumber) <= 10) {
        counter++;
        maxStreak = (counter > maxStreak) ? counter : maxStreak;
    }
    else {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
cout << maxStreak;
```

---

Here is how it works:

1. *maxStreak* stores the highest number of streak.
2. *counter* stores the number of current streak.
3. The loop starts reading from the second element of the array and compares each number in the array with the its previous number.
4. If the difference between the two numbers is equal to or less than 10, *counter* increments and *maxStreak* will be updated appropriately.
5. If the difference between the two numbers is not equal to or less than 10, *counter* will be reset to 0.

Comment: Golf! Golf! Golf!

Answer (score 0):

Remember `start` index of potential run (initially 0)

Start loop from the second index and check **every** pair  `(i++)`

Calculate **absolute** value of difference (AD) of `A[i]` and `A[i-1]`

If AD is **too large**, run is over, so find whether run length `(i-start)` is longer than previous (`maxlen`)

Check run length after loop end again

Comment: can you update the answer with some code to help me understand it better? the numbers will dupe if i use i++ so i used i += 2 instead,

Comment: You have to understand a logic. In sequence 1,2,3 you must compare both (1 and 2) and (2 and 3)

Comment: But i can't really determine how to do that without you showing the code. I tried what you said and it didn't work because i'm likely not understanding it properly. Could you show the example in code?